# reduce jagged edges and output perfect alphabet

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I have a input image:

[image: Input1]

I am normalising the image and then binarising it using OTSU.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import time
import imutils
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import re
import math
orgImg = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
orgHeight,orgWidth,_ = orgImg.shape
image = imutils.resize(orgImg,height=350)
rheight, rwidth,_= image.shape
kernel = np.ones((7,7), np.uint16)
# image = cv2.erode(image, kernel, iterations=1)
image11 = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
# Copy image to new variable
g = image11.copy()
cv2.normalize(g, g, 70, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
ret,black_mask = cv2.threshold(g,110,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow("image",black_mask)
cv2.imwrite(sys.argv[1]+"thresh.jpg",black_mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The output image is:

[image: Output1]

In the output there are many jagged edges. How do I remove these edges and get a perfect "Ca"?

Output should be something like this:

[image: Expected output]

**P.S.** Please note that the output image does not necessarily has to be binary

Comment: Could you please post all your code? I have no idea where `g` comes from or what you're doing to the image before normalizing it (if you even are doing anything)

Comment: What do you mean by 'perfect'? Do you only want to remove the frame around the letters? Or do you also want to smoothen the edges of the letters themselves? It kind of sounds like a task for OCR: Detect letters, replace them with a text overlay.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave out the resize with `imutils`, the result will look like this:

[image: Result]

I'm not sure where the extra black lines in your output image come from, because they are not created when I run you're code directly.

I changed around your code and cleaned it up a bit, it now looks like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

orgImg = cv2.imread("ca.png")

image11 = cv2.cvtColor(orgImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.normalize(image11, image11, 70, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
ret, black_mask = cv2.threshold(image11, 110, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

cv2.imshow("Original image", orgImg)
cv2.imshow("Final image", black_mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite("ca_blackmask.png", black_mask)
```

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts, I need to make this even more precise, Is it doable ?I have added expected output in the problem description